# Error to create formset factory using django-dynamic-formset

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to use two formset_factory and django dynamic formsets in the same view, but I'm getting this error 
    [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #id_form-TOTAL_FORMS:
When I try to put a prefix on the second form it just generates one id then if add more than one item it will save the last item.
I would like to know how to fix this problem and why it happened ?
thanks in advance.

my forms.py

```
class ResearchLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ResearchLines
        fields = ('title', )

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Linhas de Pesquisa'
        })
    }
LinesFormSet = formset_factory(ResearchLineForm)


class TokenForm(forms.Form):
    name =  forms.CharField( max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Linhas de Pesquisa'
        })
)
email = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Linhas de Pesquisa'
        })
 )


TokenFormSet = formset_factory(TokenForm)
```

my view.py

```
def ubc_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ubc = Ubc()
        form = UbcForm(request.POST)
        tokenformset = TokenFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = LinesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ubc.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            ubc.laboratory_departament = form.cleaned_data['laboratory_departament']
            ubc.partner_category = form.cleaned_data['partner_category']
            ubc.parent_institution_name =  form.cleaned_data['parent_institution_name']
            ubc.coordinator = form.cleaned_data['coordinator']
            if "phone" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            if "email" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if "cnpj" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.cnpj = form.cleaned_data['cnpj']
            if "rad_operating_time" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.rad_operating_time = form.cleaned_data['rad_operating_time']
            if "rh_count" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.rh_count = form.cleaned_data['rh_count']
            if "website" in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.website = form.cleaned_data['website']

            ubc.cep = form.cleaned_data['cep']
            ubc.street = form.cleaned_data['street']
            ubc.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            ubc.neighborhood = form.cleaned_data['neighborhood']
            ubc.number = form.cleaned_data['number']
            ubc.uf = form.cleaned_data['uf']
            ubc.filter_grade = 0
            ubc.grade = 0

            if 'activity_branch' in form.cleaned_data:
                ubc.activity_branch = form.cleaned_data['activity_branch']                 

            ubc.save()

        # research_lines
            if formset.is_valid():
                for researchline in formset.cleaned_data:
                    if bool(researchline):
                        created_researchline = ResearchLines.objects.create(title=researchline['title'])
                        ubc.research_line.add(created_researchline)


            product_ids = [ cert.id for cert in form.cleaned_data["main_product"] ] 
            for main_product in MainProductUbc.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids):
            ubc.main_product.add(main_product)
   )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = UbcForm()
        formset = LinesFormSet()
        tokenformset = TokenFormSet()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'formset':formset,
        'tokenformset': tokenformset,            
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/ubc_form.html', context)
```

my formset.js file

```
$('.link-formset').formset({
   deleteText: 'Remover'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formsets use #id_form-TOTAL_FORMS (and a few other things) to see how many forms there are and were initialy.

If you want to display more than one formset on a single page you'll run into the problem that you end up with two of these objects with the same id. To solve this you can define a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#customizing-a-formset-s-prefix) for one (or both) of the formsets.

Comment: thanks for your help, with that in mind I could fix the problem